# Why am I getting a tableView definition conflict?

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am taking an iOS programming class through udemy and am trying to build use the UITableViewDelegate functions to define and populate a table.

I am getting a "Definition conflicts with previous value" error, when calling cellForRowAtIndexPath, and it is referring to numberOfRowsInSection.

I am using Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//let's go ahead and define the URL that we are going to use. this literrally is saying, create a URL that Xcode can use using the string below.
    let url0 = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com")

    //let's create a task. the task will go to weather-forecast.com and get the contents.
    //first, we define the task, and then specify the method that is associated with that task.

    //we need to create an array of string values for the cities we are looking for that will be used in the task, as well as outside of the task.
    var arrayCities: [String] = []

    let task0 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url0!) {
        //NSURLSession opens an http session inside of the app.
        //.dataTaskWithURL gets the data from the URL
        //.dataTaskWithURL responds with three variables: data, response, error
        (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {

            //if error is nil, create a variable urlContent with type NSSTring, and encode data with NSUTF8StringEncoding
            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            //let's then set up a sting that we can parse correctly
            var stringParse = NSString(string: urlContent!)


            //let's start parsing urlContent and putting it into an array for us to put into a table.



            //let's see if the desired list of cities are indeed inside of the urlContent
                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">Paris Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                    arrayCities.append("Paris")
                }
                    else{println("paris has not been added")}

                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">New York Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                    arrayCities.append("New York")
                }
                    else {println("New York has not been added")}

                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">Dubai Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                    arrayCities.append("Dubai")
                }
                    else {println("Dubai has not been added")}

                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">Rome Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                    arrayCities.append("Rome")
                }
                    else {println("Rome has not been added")}

                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">Mumbai Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                    arrayCities.append("Mumbai")
                }
                    else {println("Mumbai has not been added")}


                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">London Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                arrayCities.append("London")
                }
                    else {println("London has not been added")}


                if urlContent?.rangeOfString(">Berlin Weather Forecast<") != nil{
                    arrayCities.append("Berlin")
                }
                    else {println("Berlin has not been added")}

            //println(stringParse)
            //println(urlContent)
            println(arrayCities)

            println(arrayCities.count)}
            }
    //make sure we kick off task0.
    //we do this by calling the resume() method
    task0.resume()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return arrayCities.count
    }

    //the below code will be run eveytime for every amount of rows in the table.
    //the mehtod defines the contents of each individual cell. you can put images and looks of the cells. it returns a UITable view cell, and all the content that goes with it.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //the variable indexPath tells you what row you are in everytime.

        //let's create a cell to return. the reuseIdentifier is used to create a reference name for the cell.
        //when we create and edit a prototype cell, we are referencing all the cell styles.
        //if we had a situation where we had active users that appeared red in the table and active users that appeared green, we would need to set up two seperate Prototpye cells and two reuseIdentifiers.
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayCities[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }



}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please, paste your log error if none of the two propositions below didn't help.*

**Cell Identifier**

In your `ViewController` view (storyboard), make sure you have a prototype cell. Select it and access its attributes. Make sure the `cell identifier` is the same that you use here :
`let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")`

[image: cellIdentifier]

**Reload data**

After you retrieved you data, you might want to reload the tableview :

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to me Ichamp. I already had the prototype cell made and the correct reuseIdentifier. I did not have self.tableView.reloadData()  I still had some problems, and found someone else having a similar problem [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484493/unable-to-overload-function-in-viewdidload-in-swift). I downloaded the latest version of x-code 6.2, shutdown for the night, restarted, and today the error is gone. Working on a few other errors now. Thanks again.

Comment: If the answer helped (I'm not sure it was the case if you just upgraded Xcode), please mark it as accepted.