# definition conflicts with previous value - Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6.3.2

I'm developing an iOS application in swift, which socket.io library classes written in objective C.

When I updated the Xcode to 6.3.2, I'm getting lot of errors

```
@protocol SocketIODelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveMessage:(SocketIOPacket *)packet;
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveJSON:(SocketIOPacket *)packet;
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet;
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didSendMessage:(SocketIOPacket *)packet;
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket onError:(NSError *)error;
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket onFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

When I implementing these delegate methods in swift class i'm getting "**definition conflicts with previous value**"

The implemented delegate methods in swift are like:

```
func socketIO(socket: SocketIO!, onFailWithError error: NSError!) {}

func socketIO(socket: SocketIO!, onError error: NSError!){}

func socketIO(socket: SocketIO!, didReceiveEvent packet: SocketIOPacket!) {}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Show the implemented delegate methods.

Comment: @Droppy pls check.. i have edited the question.

Comment: Is that a formal protocol?  In which case shouldn't you be using `override`?

Comment: Yes, its a formal protocol

Comment: I am probably confused about the `override` bit; I have only really used Swift 2.0 under Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: if i'm adding override also same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80986/discussion-between-dev-and-droppy).

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode 6.3.2 and implementing the delegate methods worked just fine for me.

I could only reproduce the error message you mentioned after reading this SO question here: [Unable to overload function in viewDidLoad() in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484493/unable-to-overload-function-in-viewdidload-in-swift)

This indeed fails to compile for me with *definition conflicts with previous value*:

```
func whatever() {
    func socketIO(socket: SocketIO!, onFailWithError error: NSError!) {}

    func socketIO(socket: SocketIO!, onError error: NSError!){}

    func socketIO(socket: SocketIO!, didReceiveEvent packet: SocketIOPacket!) {}
}
```

So try to move the implementation of the delegate methods out of another function, hopefully that's the issue on your side too.